# How to inject or get bean dynamically based on input value?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

Sorry I'm very new with Spring. I want to inject or get bean dynamically based on user's input value.

For example:

```
public interface PaymentGateway {}

public class PayPal implement PaymentGateway {}

public class Stripe implement PaymentGateway {}

public class Square implement PaymentGateway {}

public class PaymentService {

    @Autowired
    private final PaymentGateway gateway;

    // TODO

}
```

I let user select a payment gateway (PayPal or Stripe or Square) and inject a PaymentGateway to process. How to inject or get bean dynamically?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I think that this is the perfect scenario to apply the strategy pattern. The following link provides an great explanation for it and it also matches perfectly with your "payment implementations" scenario https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/strategy/java/example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have various ways to do that.

One of them would be the following one.

I see that `PaymentGateway` it's a `private final` which enforce you to use constructor injection, even if you put `@Autowired` on top of the member field. This means that you can create your `PaymentService` as a bean in the following way:

```
@Bean
public PaymentService paymentService(PaymentGateway gw) {
   return new PaymentService(gw);
}
```

and here you can let your client to use whatever `PaymentGateway` implementation wants.

**EDIT**

This later edit comes in order to introduce a `Dispatcher` for finding the right `PaymentGateway` bean.

First of all, introduce an enum type, let's say

```
enum PmtGatewayType {
PayPal,
Stripe,
Square
}
```

Now, in the `PaymentGateway` interface add a method like the following one:

```
public boolean accept(PmtGatewayType pmtGatewayType);
```

and implement it in the following way:

```
class Stripe implements PaymentGateway {

private PmtGatewayType gwType;

@Override
public boolean accept(PmtGatewayType pmtGwType) {

   return gwType.equals(pmtGwType);

}
```

Now, you can create another class, called `PmtGwDispatcher` where you will inject a `List` of all `PaymentGateway` beans, like the following one:

```
@Component
class PmtGwDispacher {

@Autowired
private List<PaymentGateway> pmtGateways;

public PaymentGateway select(PmtGatewayType gwType) {

PaymentGateway gw = pmtGateways.stream().filter(gw -> gw.accept(gwType)).findFirst().get();

    if(gw == null) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("The provided gateway type is invalid");
    }
    }
```

Now, in the `PaymentService` you can inject the `PmtGwDispatcher` and use it.

The solution is a little complex, but it's respecting the SOLID principles. Each component respects SRP and every time you will need to add new `PaymentGateway` you must add just a single entry in the enum and add the implementation for the new gateway.

Comment: How about inject ApplicationContext and getBean() based on input value? I use a switch-case and getBean() based on value?

Comment: This is not a good solution IMO, because your code will be coupled a lot by the framework or dependency injection context. Spring don't encourage you anymore to do this. You can use something like a Dispatcher for finding your beans. I will edit my answer with such an example.

Comment: `return gwType == pmtGwType;` equals must be here. Your edit is a correct answer, you was faster, I've been writing just that.

Comment: @Geany In Spring you can't inject beans dynamically and the usage of the multiple implementations per injected interface **is NOT** recommended.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. It should be equals. I've coded a lot in Kotlin in the last Time so this is the reason why I've put ==. :)

Comment: Thank you! I got the idea. I should not inject `ApplicationContext` because of introducing a dependency on Spring.
We have to create a new intermediate layer `Dispatch` or `Factory` to decouple with Spring Container.

Comment: @Geany I don't remember if I wrote this, `ApplicationContext` is an internal Spring infrastracture bean, should not be used outside the Spring itself.